# How do you use a button on an image that can be zoomed?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, zooming

I have placed buttons at certain parts of an image. When the user touches the button on the image the image will perform an animation. My problem is I would like to give the user the ability to zoom the image. If the image is zoomed in or out I need the button to change with the zoom so that it is always covering the same part of the image. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful. I am looking for a good place to start. Thanks for your help.